# Setting state not working after the first API call in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous, axios

I am sending a POST request to an endpoint in react using axios and if my returned response is successfull I am setting some state.

Here is my code:

```
axios.post('/some/endpoint', {mydata})
      .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data);
          if(res.data.success)
          {
            setMsg('successful');
            setActive('alert alert-success fade-out');      
          }
          else
          {
            setMsg('Oops! An error occured!');
            setActive('alert alert-danger');
          }
    })
```

After the first API request, everything is fine, I get the message and it fades out, Although If I try to send another request, It doesn't appear again and start to fade out, Why isn't the setMsg and setActive calls firing?

Heres the render:

```
    return (
      <>
        <Modal open={open} onClose={onCloseModal} center closeIcon={closeIcon} modalId="response-modal">
          <div className="qr-modal-header-stock">
            <h5>Enter fulfillment stock</h5>
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p>Fulfilment Center: {fulfilmentCenterName}</p>
            <p>Existing stock: {stock}</p>
            <p className={active} style={{opacity:0}}>{msg}</p>    <-- this appears firstly but not the second time when I submit the form, why?
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="hidden" name="ean" value={data} />
                <input type="hidden" name="product_stock" value={newStock} />
                <input type="number" class="form-control" onChange={e => setNewStock(parseInt(e.target.value) + parseInt(stock))}/> <br />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="submit-fulfilment-center" value="Save"/>
            </form>
            <br />
            <p>New stock: {isNaN(newStock) ? 0 : newStock}</p>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={onCloseModal}>Scan another ean</button>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </ >
    );
```

Comment: Do you ever reset the className? I think this might be a css problem. Is it possible that you fade out the message and then never fade it back in (i.e. it's still there, but you can't see it any more)?

Comment: thats true, i never fade it back in and never reset the className, but everytime it should "re-add" the classes and hence start the fade-out process again

Comment: It will not "re-add" anything. If the classes are already there, they will stay there and will not animate any fade-outs again. You need to remove the classes before you can "re-add" them and "re-fade".

Comment: In fact, if you call a useState (which I assume is what setActive is) with the exact same value twice, react will not even acknowledge that you called it the second time. It considers re-rendering to be redundant, since nothing has changed.

Comment: yes thats true, I tested it now, thanks

Comment: i got it to work by addig  onAnimationEnd={() => {setActive("")}}

Answer (score 0):

You should use "useState" hook and watch "Msg" and "Active" states for changes.

```
useState(()=>{
    // do somthing here 
},[Msg,Active])
```

using this will re-render the page every time the value of "Msg" or "Active" changes.

**Notice : Do Not set states and watch them in the same useState hook , this will will cause an infinite rendring loop**